# Single word request: a non-changing temporal trend

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

Is there a word for describing a non-changing temporal trend? Stasis?

E.g. expenditure on health care did not change between 2000-2020.

Comment: You sure are stingy with your context and description of the requested word! In your other question too! Do you need a noun, an adjective, verb maybe? Please give a complete sentence leaving a space ______ where the term would be placed in your sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Health care expenditures are not a trend. They are an occurrence. If you are comparing such occurrences year-to-year, month-to-month, or whatever, the usual adjective is *unchanged from..." whatever period you're comparing them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I can make any sense out of the given information, the word you seem to be looking for is **constant.**

> INVARIABLE, UNIFORM

[Merriam-Webster]

So you could say *Expenditure on healthcare remained constant during 2000-2020.*